# Как доработать блок?

Tags: html, css, jquery, swiper

Как доработать блок?
Cлайдер работает. Свапом ( в этом и суть). Но раскладка не такая как на скрине. В этом и проблема

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<!-- Swiper -->
<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QFmbQ8t/Rectangle-1850.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wBLL2NL/Rectangle-1853.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BfG5cGQ/Rectangle-1851.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XCmdMC3/Rectangle-1855.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/QFmbQ8t/Rectangle-1850.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wBLL2NL/Rectangle-1853.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/BfG5cGQ/Rectangle-1851.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XCmdMC3/Rectangle-1855.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>

<!-- Swiper JS -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@9/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: false,
    slidesPerGroupSkip: 1,
    grabCursor: true,
    keyboard: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    scrollbar: {
      el: ".swiper-scrollbar",
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true,
    },
  });
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос информацию, о том, что у вас не получается.

Comment: Что вы хотите вообще непонятно, по ссылке прошёл, там вообще неработающий слайдер, а не блоки картинок.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи: _"Как доработать блок?"_ - это философский вопрос, он не имеет конкретного решения, а предполагает пространные размышления о правильности выбора профессии. А по ссылке слайдер работает, но только свайпом/драгом.

Comment: @UModeL, Возможно, не совсем корректный мой вопрос. Может так правильно -как доработать раскладку, чтобы было как на скрине?

Comment: @Евгений Ли, сам слайдер работает. Свапом ( в этом и суть). Но раскладка не такая как на скрине. В этом и проблема

Comment: @UModeL, понимаю, вопрос откорректирован. Не глянете на саму проблему ,пожалуйста?

Comment: @olya096 я так понял, вы хотите в одном слайде отображать по два изображения, и чтобы они чередовались по размеру?